# Accessing a Function of an Already Deployed Smart Contract on Ropsten Test Network

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I have already deployed a smart contract for my custom ERC20 Token on the Ropsten Test Network. Now I am creating a new smart contract and within a function I need to call the transfer() function of the Token. I am unable to figure out how to do so. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you want to transfer an ERC20 token in a smart contract, either the contract holds the token, or the contract has been authorized by a wallet to call its ERC20 token!

Comment: If you can add more specific details and steps, that would be helpful to the op.

Comment: There are many tutorials on the Internet on how to do this